# Formatting hstore column Postgres

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to find the best way to format a hstore column (see screenshot) my goal is to have the same format based on the screenshot as the "updated_column. I was thinking about a case statement like :

Case when json_column -> id then 'id:'

any suggestion would be appreciated.[image]

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which data type should your column have and which is it right now?

Comment: currently is in json format, and I need to turn it into a string @LenglBoy

Comment: JSON got advantages: sub indexes, schema validation, faster search - just queries are more complex and needs more data.

Beside that - needed for migration? Hopefully your app stores string direkt and parses it. There should no logic/parsing on DB side since that will be slow.
Migrate the current fields and data and change your source/app to directly provide the string you need.

Comment: I use the query in a BI tool that type of manipulation is not supported by the tool so I have to use a custom SQL query @LenglBoy.

Comment: @CerealBox Better provide a view that the BI tool can use, instead of migrating your data away from JSON. In fact that view should probably have one column per JSON property that you're interested in, not use some custom string format.

Comment: Are you sure that is a `json` type column? It looks much more like a `hstore`.

Comment: @Bergi I just confirmed and it is hstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think i found a temporary solution that will work, but I think like @Bergi mentioned a view might be more appropriate.

For now I will just use something like:

```
   concat(concat(concat(concat('id',':',column -> 'id')
    ,' ','auth_id',':',column -> 'auth_id')
    ,' ','type',':',column -> 'type')
    ,' ','transaction',':',column -> 'transaction')
```

Comment: This example is very closer to only cover your need for this case. Not that useful for reusing.

Answer (score 0):

Migration approach:

- Add new column with type `text` like you want it
- make sure new data directly enters the new column as the string you want (pre-formatted at the backend)
- Create a migration function that converts json column data batchwise into your new string table. You can use postgres replace/.. operations to reformat it. You can also use an external python script/...
- remove the json column after the migration is done

Let me see what / how you have tried and then we can see how to improve/solve your issues.

Comment: If your data source only persits json but your reading part only understand stirng you can implement a man in the middle or have a stored function/trigger that converts incoming json to that string you want so it can be read again by the other tool. 
Please note: that takes performance and is not optimal (total situation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some function to make it generic:

Let's get some example:

```sql
 select '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json;
┌───────────────┐
│     json      │
├───────────────┤
│ {"a":1,"b":2} │
└───────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Back to text:

```sql
select '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json::text;
┌───────────────┐
│     text      │
├───────────────┤
│ {"a":1,"b":2} │
└───────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Now, remove the undesired tokens `{}"` with a regex:

```sql
select regexp_replace('{"a":1,"b":2}'::json::varchar, '["{}]+', '', 'g');
┌────────────────┐
│ regexp_replace │
├────────────────┤
│ a:1,b:2        │
└────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

and you can wrap it into a function:

```sql
create function text_from_json(json) returns text as $$select regexp_replace($1::text, '["{}]+', '', 'g')$$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Testing the function now:

```sql
tsdb=> select text_from_json('{"a":1,"b":2}'::json);
┌────────────────┐
│ text_from_json │
├────────────────┤
│ a:1,b:2        │
└────────────────┘
```

Comment: Notice the OP actually has `hstore` values, not `json` values

Comment: Also, don't use regex. Better properly loop over the key-value pairs and `string_agg` them into the desired format.

Comment: Thanks for the support @Bergi! I originally thought they were interoperable but it seems hstore is a plain structure not allowing substructures.  I also simplified the structure based on his example using very simple values and it would be very messy if the values include the tokens I was removing.